# Pass list item from controller to javascript function and search item in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Please everyone help me!

I have a list of items in controller, each item contains 2 attribute, it like a tabe including 2 column:

`|--ID--|--Value--|
|  A   |    2    |
|  B   |    4    |
|  C   |    5    |
|  D   |    8    |`

I pass the list from controller to javascript using ViewBag:

`var Drinks =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Drinks));`

I have a Dropdown in the view, It contains a list of IDs.

I have a text box, I need it to be automatically filled in by the value selected in the dropdown.

**The list in the viewbag and the dropdown list are different!**
Dropdown lists contain more IDs

example:

$('#Dropdown').val()='C';

Search the list ID = 'C' then set $('#Textbox').val() = '5';

Thank for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the format of the json object, but something like this should help you to move forward:

```js
    var json = [
      { value: "A" },
      { value: "C" },
      { value: "E" },
      { value: "G" },
      { value: "I" }
    ];

    $("#select").on("change", function () {
      var dropDownList = $(this);
      var selectedValue = dropDownList.val();
      
      var selectedObject = json.find(v => v.value === selectedValue);
      
      if (selectedObject !== null && selectedObject !== undefined) {
        $("#textToUpdate").val(dropDownList.find("option:selected").text());
      } else {
        $("#textToUpdate").val("");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="select">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="A">Drink 1</option>
      <option value="B">Drink 2</option>
      <option value="C">Drink 3</option>
      <option value="D">Drink 4</option>
      <option value="E">Drink 5</option>
      <option value="F">Drink 6</option>
      <option value="G">Drink 7</option>
      <option value="H">Drink 8</option>
      <option value="I">Drink 9</option>
      <option value="J">Drink 10</option>
    </select>

    <input id="textToUpdate" type="text" value="This will be updated" />
```